# If a conductivity meter is calibrated with aqueous standards, can it be used to measure the conductivity of an organic-based solvent system?

Tags: acid-base, solutions, conductivity

Trying to figure out if the calibration solutions for a conductivity probe/meter must be of a similar nature to the system which will be measured. I can only find aqueous calibration solutions online, and the solvent systems that I need to monitor are ethanol and methanol based. If I use the aqueous calibration solutions, will my measurements in the organic systems be accurate?

Comment: I don't know of any fundamental theoretical reason why you would need to match solvents.  However, it seems like a very easy empirical test!  Make some lithium acetate solutions of known concentration in water, in methanol, and in ethanol, and then compare the results!